# How to transform a streaming IP video into a CATV signal?

Tags: rf

I wanted to create a circuit, where a network cable was connected, and then the eprom, connected to a video stream in IP, after that streaming, it was converted to RF (CATV). What kind of things should I start to learn and where. I know that for example this messes with QAM or TDM Modulation (only if you want to transmit more than one channel on the same frequency). But unfortunately I can't find anything about this type of content on the internet. Where on the internet, or in reading, could you find more about this subject?

Comment: you need a compter with a VGA output connected to a VGA RF modulator ... or something like a Raspberry Pi that has an RCA video putput, connected to an RF modulator ... use off the shelf components

Comment: I agree that this is *possible*, and it would be a cool project, but it would also be complicated, and you probably can't do it yet if you haven't recognized that already.

Comment: And yes, there will be at least one computer in your circuit.

Comment: I suspect part of your problem might be that you're still struggling with the basics. For instance, as the accepted answer already points out, you use the word "circuit" in a unique way. And I have no idea what exactly you mean by "the eprom". Another sign is that you don't break up your problem in manageable steps. I.e. generate a static test image signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I wanted to create a circuit,

Um, no. What you describe encompasses at least one relatively beefy computer that has a network interface and runs an operating system with a network stack.

> What kind of things should I start to learn and where.

Honestly, "recognizing things you can and cannot build with your current resources" is what you should learn first.

Essentially, you're saying "I want to build a high-bandwidth SDR and a cable television encoder; then some amplifiers to supply a CATV network, potentially".

You, however, don't seem to be aware of much of the underlying technology. It would indicate that the first thing you'd need to learn is how to look up things!

For example, "Cable TV" is an article on Wikipedia, and you might want to look into the standards mentioned there.

Then, you'd look up the standards (and will hopefully decide that implementing them yourself is a job for a group of experienced engineers with lots of background in the field, not for a one-off project), and then look for existing products or implementations.

There's ready-to-buy Cable TV modulators, and that's very likely the route you want to take (PC to receive your video stream + GPU + Modulator). If you actually want to build an SDR system of your own, you'd start looking for DVB-C implementations on the internet (you'll find a lot about GNU Radio).

Comment: Thanks, for the tips, but wikipedia, just talks about the concepts, including, I've been on this page before, I've read a lot about this subject, including even some videos about DAC, ADC, QAM, ISDB-C, ISDB-T, etc. And now I'm going to research more about software-defined radio. Now I would like to move on to practice. I built it initially to test and understand how an AM and FM transmitter (FM in simulation) works. But ok, I understand that, these are more complex things to do and much less at my age, I really have to learn this only at university.

Comment: @TheCoder Age is not a barrier, but understanding is. You can find the cable TV standard specifications (there could be more than one - I don't know!) and pore over them if you want. It will take a lot of time and a lot of trial-and-error, but it is possible, but you might not want to do it because it will take a long time. (Also I don't know if the standards are free; there's a chance you might have to pay for them)

Comment: Thanks @user253751 I've been researching, and I think I found, some documentation on the subject.

Comment: @TheCoder well good luck! Even if you don't succeed, you might learn something, so it could still be worth it.